# Trying to add CANopenNode library but getting errors

Tags: git, stm32, mbed, canopen

https://github.com/Alphatronics/mbed-os-example-canopen trying to add this library for stm32f429zi nucleo but couldn't been able to do so.
Tried install both manually and with mbed studio.

While manually installing with "mbed import mbed-os-example-canopen" got this:
ERROR: Unable to clone repository (https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-canopen)

I used git clone too and got this:
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-canopen/' not found
(tried changing repository too,didn't work.)

And finally,with mbed studio while trying to import the library got this error:
An error happened while processing the library https://github.com/Alphatronics/CANopenNode/. Commit a8e50277052bfb3194358eda21b663a065265d7d does not exist

I'm sorry in advance if this is an easy problem but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: `https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-canopen` does not exist. The only CAN example repo on ARMmbed is `https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-snippet-CAN_ex_1`